# UserProvider from custom composer package [Symfony 4]

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, symfony4

I got a tricky question today,

Is it possible to have a custom UserProvider from a vendor in symfony 4 ?
For the moment I got this error :

```
The service "security.context_listener.0" has a dependency on a non-existent service "Hello\UserProvider".
```

Comment: It's certainly possible.  If the vendor code is a bundle then you need to see what services it defines.  If it is not a bundle then you will need to define any needed services in your services.yaml file.

Comment: Yes it can be done.
Create a provider class.
Configure security bundle. [link](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_provider.html#creating-a-custom-user-provider)